# My answer was turned into a comment

Tags: discussion, comment, specific-answer

In the question [“It looks straightforward, but actually it isn't”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415365/it-looks-straightforward-but-actually-it-isnt)   I gave an answer which was turned into this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415365/it-looks-straightforward-but-actually-it-isnt#comment889536_415365).

I understand that there are a couple of reasons to turn my answer into a comment, but I also think there are stronger reasons to leave it as an answer, namely the fact that as an un-upvoted comment it will easily get buried and not get due attention and the fact that as an answer is gets a lot more exposure. I'm assuming no one disagrees that that link should have a decent exposure on that question.

Another reason is because this sort of answer is, in some instances, well received. I don't remember others at the moment, but [here's one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/410475/55235) - which I personally consider to be one of the best.

What relative differences are there between my answer and that one?

Apparently I can undelete my answer. Not sure if I'll be able to, but at least the undelete button is available. Despite that, there's no point in undeleting if the community feels it should stay as a comment.

So I ask you to vote on the appropiate answers below wether you feel it should stay as a comment or it should be undeleted. Please don't downvote the voting answers.

If it happens to stay as a comment, then I urge you to at least upvote enough it enough for it not to be lost.

---

I just ran into [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42624/double-sum-miklos-schweitzer-2010#comment99764_44721) comment which contradicts what I've been told in this question and what (apparently) the community feels it should be done. Double standard much?

Comment: Just FYI: you [might find difficulty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/214632) in attempting to undelete your post.  (Though you can flag another post of yours and request undeletion of the post in question.)

Comment: And one difference between the two answers (though not intrinsic to either) is that one was multiply flagged as "not an answer" while the other received no such flags.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Good to know about the undeletion and lol at the last comment. Thanks.

Comment: Such things are sometimes done automatically by software, although it doses not seem to be the case here. See: [What constitutes a trivial answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6501/what-constitutes-a-trivial-answer)

Comment: @GitGud: although the answer you cited got a large number of votes, it should have perhaps copied, with attribution, part or all of the list from Wikipedia. Link-only answers are far less useful if the link should go stale.

Comment: @robjohn I was under the impression that it should be that way, however I've seen the opposite happening: a link being accepted as an answer even after people mentioning it is just a link. I can't recall what question it was, though.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513223/example-of-ring-without-the-distributive-property)'s another example that just came up in this recent [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/561086/55235).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\Huge \text{Leave it as a comment!}$

Comment: This matter is settled.

Answer (score -1):

$\Huge \text{Undelete it!}{}{}{}{}$